# Is it good practice to pass `char []` to a function which accepts `std::string&`

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers

I am not facing any issues with below code but is it good practice to pass `char []` to a function which accepts `std::string&` as a parameter

```
 const char* function(std::string& MyString)
 {
    MyString = "Hello World";
    return MyString.c_str();
 }

 int main()
 {
    char MyString[50];

    /*
    *Is it good practice to cast like this?
    *what possible issues i could face because of this casting?
    */
    function((std::string)MyString);                  

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: That depends on the details of the function. In this case it actually won't work if you try to save the return value of `function` past the line you call it on, because the return value only lives as long as the string you call it with. But that's a slightly different issue; thinking of lifetime management in terms of just the creation of temporary objects leaves some stuff out. In general, it might involve unnecessary copies to construct the `std::string`; you can do that if you need to, but it's probably better to write the function to use `std::string_view` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simply won't work because it will require creation of temporary `std::string` which can not be bound to l-value reference. Even if function took a reference to `std::string const` creation of temporary would have an impact of performance. So depending on nature of the function it may be a good idea to add an overload that accepts a pointer to a c-string as well. Alternatively, if function is not going to modify the string you can make it accept `std::string_view` so it can handle both `std::string` and c-strings.

Comment: Yes VC++ allowing it

Comment: @AlanBirtles @BreakBadSP Most likely you are compiling in non-conformance mode. Use `/permissive-` and `/Zc:rvalueCast`

Answer (score 1):

No, it is bad practice, as the cast has no effect; a `std::string` can be constructed from a `char *` with a non-explicit constructor, so you can remove the cast and you'll get exactly the same code (just with an implicit construction instead of an explicit cast).

Now as written, you'll get an error (at least with a non-broken compiler), as you can't pass a temporary object to a non-const lvalue reference.  But if you change the function to take a `const std::string &`, it will work just fine.

Also bad practice is returning the `char *` you get by calling std::string::c_str() -- this pointer will only be valid as long as the string object is not modified or destroyed -- so the returned pointer will become invalid (dangling) as soon a the temp you passed as an argument was destroyed.  If you were to save that returned pointer in a local variable in main and then try to do something with it (like printing it), that would be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In short passing `char[]` to function accepting string is common practice (from C). And it is not bad. The explicit cast is not good here. The function also is not good, as it not accept passing `char[]` ...

Comment: Also if you use reference because you need alter string inside a function (and this should be a result visible to caller), you cannot use `char[]` (or something else) if there is `string`. and it is the question again if it is good.